# Sending 2 bytes hexadecimal to a remote serial

Tags: c, linux

I only need to send a hexadecimal like this to a remote serial for the device to accept it.

2 byte hexadecimal I need to send is:

```
181E
```

I can telnet to the remote serial and send that command:

```
telnet x.x.x.x port

181E
```

I get a response back which is okay.

How can I do this in linux c?

I want to use the write function.

```
err = write(socket,181E,2);
```

Or How can I store the 2 byte decimal to a variable so It will be read as 181E?

```
int this_is_2_bytes = 181E; // Is this correct?

err = write(socket, this_is_2_bytes, sizeof(this_is_2_bytes));
```

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but you should probably be using "expect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a *hexadecimal string*. So,

```
const char cmd[] = "181E";
err = write(socket, cmd, strlen(cmd));
```

Comment: I'm getting undeclared cmd when doing it like that. So I just changed it to const char cmd[] = "181E"; which works.

Comment: Oops, Java creeping in there, fixed.

Comment: How do I add a press enter after I sent the 181E?. Can i make it like this const char cmd[] = "181E\r";

Comment: Sure, add `\r\n`, whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

No, writing an int is not correct on all systems.  Write a two-element byte array.

Comment: Doing it like this unsigned char cmd[] = {0x18, 0x1E}; err = write(socket,cmd,sizeof(cmd)); does not work. the character sent to the device is like this "(" which i got an error.

Answer (score 0):

The write() function requires a pointer as the second argument.Store it in in character array.